# How to run MongoDB query with lock document for later update?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to find accurate answer for this situation in MongoDB, but couldn't get satisfactory answer from any source.

Many people familiar with this example in Database training, Just explaining in-case anyone needs. This is the example in DB2. Person-1's account balance is $100.00. Person-1 goes to teller/ATM to deposit $20.00 into his account, the balance updates has following steps in system. For better understanding, I am providing event time.

1. At 9:00:00:000 AM, Read Person-1's account record to find current
   balance (DB2 locks record). Read in DB2 is equivalent to mongoDB
   query, DB2 has record level lock mechanisms with read.
2. At 9:00:00:001 AM, Some checks on account and Add $20 to 100 = $120,
   say this step takes 2 seconds (it won't usually, just to have better
   time to understand update mechanics)
3. At 9:00:02:001, Update $120 to Person-1's account record in DB2.

Person-1's friend transfers $30 on internet at 9:00:00:001
If System reads Person-1's account at this time for update, it add $30 to 100 and final balance will become $130 or $120 based on which balance update happens later. But the balance should be $150.

To avoid the error, DB2 puts update lock on record in above step-1, therefore Internet transfer transaction can't read balance for update until step-3 is complete (step-3 automatically releases lock). Besides, Other threads can read record at anytime as long as it's not reading for update.

Note: DB2 locks only person-1's account record in this case, not entire table (collection) as other account updates can continue at same time.

Can someone please explain how this is achieved in mongoDB? I heard some people saying use flag in document and control thru application program, but that's not accurate, it can also cause loosing balance in above case.

Thanks
Nar

Comment: Have you looked at the [transaction support](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) that's now available in 4.0?

Comment: Yes, It doesn't have anything for what I am looking for. Just to add, transaction processing has nothing to do with what I am looking here, at least in DB2 terms. I could disable transaction processing in DB2 and still achieve read-lock and update.

Answer (score 3):

> Can someone please explain how this is achieved in mongoDB?

There are few items to unpack here, but let's start with the basic [MongoDB multi-document Transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/transactions/).

If the update operations are performed inside of a transactional session, the second update operation will be blocked until the first transaction has been committed, aborted, or expired. See more information about this behaviour on [MDBW18: How and When to Use Multi-Document Distributed Transactions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3x_Pf9rQGCo&feature=youtu.be&t=12m)

For example (Based on MongoDB v4.0.3), if you have a document as below:

```
{"person": "one", "balance": NumberDecimal(100)}
```

With an update operation as below:

```
s1 = Mongo().startSession() ;
sessionFoo = s1.getDatabase("databaseName").collectionName;
s1.startTransaction();
var result = sessionFoo.update({"person":"one"}, {"$set":{"balance":120}});
// ...
s1.commitTransaction();
```

If another update operation (similar as above) happens before the `commitTransaction`, it will receive a `TransientTransactionError`. Error output example:

```
"errorLabels" : [
    "TransientTransactionError"
],
"operationTime" : Timestamp(1540175676, 1),
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "Unable to acquire lock '{7817449386782089629: Database, 899920359141007773}' within a max lock request timeout of '5ms' milliseconds.",
"code" : 24,
"codeName" : "LockTimeout",
```

> At 9:00:02:001, Update $120 to Person-1's account record in DB2

Generally, you don't update to a value, but perform an event increment ([$inc operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/)) of the value. So instead of :

```
var result = sessionFoo.update({"person":"one"}, {"$set":{"balance":120}});
```

It would be:

```
var result = sessionFoo.update({"person":"one"}, {"$inc":{"balance":20}});
```

To extend this further, normally for finance related records, you would like to capture events instead of the state. See also [Even Sourcing](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html). For example instead of below:

```
t1: balance 100 
t2: balance 120
t3: balance 150 
t4: balance 70
```

Where `balance` represents the state of balance at time `t`. It would be events such as:

```
t1: balance 100 
t2: balance +20 
t3: balance +30 
t4: balance -80
```

This is so that there is a historical records for a point in time. i.e. replay transactions since 48 hours ago.

> DB2 locks only person-1's account record in this case, not entire table (collection) as other account updates can continue at same time

Please note that in MongoDB, an operation on a single document is atomic (even without the transaction feature). This is because you can use [embedded](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/#embedded-data-models) documents and arrays to capture relationships between data in a single document structure instead of normalising across multiple documents and collections, this single-document atomicity obviates the need for multi-document transactions for many practical use cases. See also [MongoDB Data Model Design](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/).